# How to apt install package from PPA with same release name as official repo in an ARM computer?

Tags: apt, ppa, blender

I am trying to install blender 2.8 from [here](https://launchpad.net/~thomas-schiex/+archive/ubuntu/blender). I've run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thomas-schiex/blender
sudo apt-get update
```

However, when I run `apt search blender`, it still shows me the version 2.79 version from the official `bionic-updates` repo.

I would try and specify the exact repo, but this ppa names the release as `bionic main`, i.e. super generic terms that overlap with the official names.

I've tried removing the sources.list file so that only the blender package in the ppa repo would get found, but that doesn't work either (Blender is simply not found at all). It seems as though the ppa is not seen by my system.

Edit: Result of `apt-cache policy blender`:

```
blender:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.79.b+dfsg0-1ubuntu1.18.04.1
  Version table:
     2.79.b+dfsg0-1ubuntu1.18.04.1 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/universe arm64 Packages
     2.79.b+dfsg0-1 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/universe arm64 Packages
```

Edit2: Running `sudo apt update` confirms that we're hitting the ppa:

```
...
Hit:9 http://international.download.nvidia.com/jetson/repos/common r32 InRelease
Hit:10 http://international.download.nvidia.com/jetson/repos/t210 r32 InRelease
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thomas-schiex/blender/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic InRelease
Hit:14 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports InRelease
Hit:17 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

... but it's still showing only version 2.79 as an option.

Comment: please [edit] and add the output of `apt-cache policy blender`

Comment: `sudo apt install blender` will install the ppa version. So what's the actual question here? ( maybe why doesn't apt search find this ppa's package??

Comment: @doug `sudo apt install blender` does not in my case. It installs the 2.79 version from ubuntu's bionic-updates/universe. When I comment out those repos in source.list, my system detects no blender whatsoever. Seems like it's just not seeing the ppa

Comment: It looks like you didn't add the repository properly. Please post the output of `sudo apt update` command to your question.

Comment: I am puzzled. You've added the repo OK.

Comment: I wrote an answer. Your arch is `arm64`. That's the reason.

Comment: Ok, thank you all for the help/clarification. It's a jetson nano with Ubuntu 18.04, hence arm64. I know that ubuntu 19.10 on my rpi4 has blender 2.8 through the ubuntu repo, so I'll see if I can get that version installed.

Answer (score 3):

Your architecture seems to be `arm64`.

There are no `arm64` (only `amd64`) packages in that PPA.

If you need blender version from that PPA, you'll have to build it yourself from source.

Answer (score 0):

Magnus, there is likely an issue in your setup. Please check that when you do "apt  update", it lists the PPA. You should see a line containing the following text:

http://ppa.launchpad.net/thomas-schiex/blender/ubuntu bionic InRelease

If you don't see it, then the PPA is not a source for you. There may be other issues, but this one is the most likely.

BTW, because the PPA is updated more frequently than versions of blender, the blender version numbering is based on the git commit number and hash. This is always increasing. It should (and has for several years) make update easy.